# How to sync the latest transaction of an account which has enabled 2FA in Yodlee?

Tags: webhooks, yodlee, open-banking

I have a CapitalOne account that has enabled 2FA. I am receiving transactions when I link my account using FastLink as below images,
[image]
[image]

After the above-mentioned process, I made a few transactions for testing purposes. But they haven't got synced. What I realized is that it is not get synced after linking the account. Also, I am not receiving any event through the webhook.

I have written this on StackOverflow after getting fed up with the Yodlee support team as they were not able to give correct information to sort out my issue.
Also, I would like to know whether I can use Yodlee Dummy Account to test this kind of scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If account is 2fa enabled I don't think there will be a scheduled sync to get new transactions. You need to check other API's to get updates.